# Pair of Lines in Map function as input in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have one big file. It has multiple lines in the following format.

```
Line1:  2 3 1 6 7
Line2:  9 3 4 5 6
Line3:  2 2 2 3 3
Line4:  1 2 5 6 7
```

In the mapper function I need to push 2 lines at a time. (the combination will be unique). What I mean is that in the mapper function, I need to get it like:

```
(Line 1 & Line 2)
(Line 1 & Line 3)
(Line 1 & Line 4)
(Line 2 & Line 3)
(Line 2 & Line 4)
(Line 3 & Line 4)
```

That is total 4C2 = 6 unique combination here.
In that case how can I achieve that? What specific input format I need to use?

Comment: perhaps a pre-processing job that generates those combinations and then gives pairs of input lines to the second job (could be too wasteful though)

Comment: @vefthym : Thanks for the idea. I have thought about that too. But it will also take a lot time to process it before as it is a big file.

Comment: keep in mind that generating pairs has a quadratic complexity, so i don't know if you have many options here

Comment: @vefthym : yes that is true. need to think about something else.   One more thing, is it possible to share the file content to each mapper(client) without reading it each time in the map() or configure() function.? Here I have used  conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);  and want to access one particular file always.

Comment: Basically I need one distinct line from the file and the file content in map function.